# html2Canvas and canvas2Image: how to download and store converted image in local storage?

Tags: html2canvas

I'm using html2Canvas and canvas2Image plugins for taking screenshot of the webpage using JavaScript.
I'm trying to store both canvas and canvas2Image(in png format) by assigning to variables, but those variables are undefined after assigning. In addition, converted canvas is appending directly to DOM. So,

1. How to avoid appending that canvas to DOM?
2. How to download those screenshots(images)?
3. How to store those images in local storage instead of directly appending to DOM?
4. Is there any other good plugin for taking screenshots using javascript Other than html2Canvas?